# Label Not showing up on interface

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So i just want this text to get placed but its not showing up. I used .grid so i need to use.place to make sure it doesnt get all messed up. Unless someone can help me do otherwise? Thanks!

```
import tkinter as ttk
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = ttk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.title("New window")

# -------------get date information---------- #

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%y")

# grab image

imagepath = "D:\\Programing\\BG_sky.jpg"
background_picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagepath))


# ------------build window ------------------#


date = ttk.Label(root, text=dt_string, font='helvetica')
# date.pack(side="left")

date.place(x=10, y=10)

backgroundimage = ttk.Label(root, 
image=background_picture)
backgroundimage.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", 
expand="yes")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it because you are packing the `backgroundimage` *over* the `date` label? What happens if you pack `backgroundimage` first, and then place your `date` label?

Comment: I think i love you. Thanks man

Comment: You can use date.lift() to lift it to the top.